# Add preprocessor macro for another pod

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I'm creating a CocoaPod framework (Pod B) that has a dependency on another CocoaPod framework (Pod A).  Some of the behavior and file locations used by Pod A are controlled by preprocessor macros.  Is there a way I can supply some of these macros from Pod B so that users of Pod B do not have to be aware of or deal with the settings required by Pod A?

I've tried setting some of these in XCode, but it seems that building Pod A does not take any of these settings from XCode.  It would be preferable not to have to modify Pod A's .xcconfig unless that could be automated as part of either the build process or Pod B's install.

**Update**
The CocoaPods team seems to have [talked about solving](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Core/issues/243) this issue, but I can't see if any work has been done on this.  Wondering if anyone has tried to solve this in other ways.

I would really prefer to avoid the standard mechanism of having a `post_install` in the Podfile, since that would require Pod B's users to make that change and hence be aware of these settings.

Answer (score -1):

Would defining/re-defining the macros in Pod B's headers be acceptable to you?  For example, if Pod A defined `foo`, & you wanted it to be defined to something different, you could add something like the following to `Pod_B.h`:

```
#ifdef foo
#undef foo
#endif
#define foo bar
```

Of course, you'd replace `Pod_B.h` with Pod B's header, & `foo` and `bar` with the macros & whatever you want to define them to.

#### edit

apperantly, that wouldn't work, but you might be able to build Pod A as a subproject of Pod B, which would insulate the users from it, & still allow other projects to use Pod A in a way that's incompatible with Pod B.

Comment: These settings need to be in effect before Pod A is built and Pod A does not include Pod_B.h.  Might be possible if the Podfile rebuilt Pod A's headers using Pod_B.h but that would be quite brittle.  The idea is for clients of Pod B to specify some setting that would cause changes in the macros used to build Pod A without them having to know (or care) about the internal workings of Pod A.

Comment: Sorry, I was confused.